# Call python function from robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to figure out what am I doing wrong,
I want to get the result of a specific python function.

This is my Resources.robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                           resources_func.py

*** Keywords ***
Test Time
    ${time_delta}=                get time period        ${Time}
```

- ${Time} is defined but isn't relevant to my question

and this is my python script:

```
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse

class TimeTests(object):
    def get_time_period(timestamp):
        timestamps = re.findall(r'[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]', timestamp)
        a = parse(timestamp[0])
        b = parse(timestamp[1])
        res = (b - a)
        res = res.seconds / 60
        return res
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
No keyword with name 'get time period' found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: rename filename resources_func.py to classname : resources_func.py > TimeTests.py and try again.

Comment: That worked!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For others in future, have a look into RF docs about creating user libraries
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id216

> The name of a test library that is used when a library is imported is
>   the same as the name of the module or class implementing it. For
>   example, if you have a Python module MyLibrary (that is, file
>   MyLibrary.py), it will create a library with name MyLibrary.
>   Similarly, a Java class YourLibrary, when it is not in any package,
>   creates a library with exactly that name.
>
> Python classes are always inside a module. If the name of a class
>   implementing a library is the same as the name of the module, Robot
>   Framework allows dropping the class name when importing the library.
>   For example, class MyLib in MyLib.py file can be used as a library
>   with just name MyLib. This also works with submodules so that if, for
>   example, parent.MyLib module has class MyLib, importing it using just
>   parent.MyLib works. If the module name and class name are different,
>   libraries must be taken into use using both module and class names,
>   such as mymodule.MyLibrary or parent.submodule.MyLib.